# Ubuntu 14.04 on Thinkpad T440S keyboard Issue

Tags: 14.04, thinkpad, pipe

I installed Ubuntu Trusty on a brand new lenovo Thinkpad.  So far things are going well except for the following:

The pipe key gives the < symbol, and when shift is pressed, it gives the > symbol.  It's a bit impossible to run commands this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have the US keyboard enabled, rather than the UK.

Keyboard layouts are managed from within settings.  When you have the dialogue open, click the button at the bottom which says 'Text Entry' and a list of available keyboard layouts appears.  You can add more if you need to or just select the UK option from the list.

You may also have a link in the taskbar, amongst the other icons.  It shows 'En'.  Click on it and it shows a list of installed keyboard layouts, select English (UK) if it appears.  If not then install it as above.